# Issue with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to have the child image appear in a new division it places it outside the HTML tag and cuts off bottom on save any suggestions?

I was able to get Clone to work TY for that advise... But my upload is still missing app. 50 pixels from bottom of image .....  Still have not figured out how to return the image URL back and would like to get the clone to appear Directly under my generated image and not off page.....  any advise on that?

```
          function screenshot(){
                html2canvas(document.getElementById("capture")).then(function(canvas) {   


                     var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[2];
                     var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
                     document.body.appendChild(cln);

                    // Get base64URL
                    var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg').replace('image/jpg', 'image/octet-stream');

                    // AJAX request
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajaxfile.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {image: base64URL},
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log('Upload successfully.');
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
```

Here is my ajaxfile

```
$image = $_POST['image'];

$location = "upload/";

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);

$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
$filename = date("m_j_y-H_i_s").'.png';

$file = $location . $filename;
$imageurl  = 'upload/'.$filename.'.png';


file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

echo $filename;
echo $file;
echo $location;
echo $image;
```

Comment: Also I have not been able to return the $filename from my submission it does capture and upload without any other issues.

Comment: you need clone element for canvas then after canvas done, append it to

Comment: I am very new at this and truely do not understand it could you give an example?